# How to reset command line Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a weird Segmentation Fault on my Swift installation.

`Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1). Type :help for assistance.
Segmentation fault: 11`

How can I reset it? Is there a command or hidden folder to be nuked?

Comment: Is it normal that the swift version differs from the clang version?

Comment: @Rudi yes it is (I have the exact same setup as my colleagues in that respect)